# BIML GetDropAndCreateDdl creating incorrect lengths for datatypes

Tags: t-sql, biml

When I use GetDropAndCreateDdl to generate CREATE scripts for tables, I get datatypes for columns that are different than what the datatypes actually are.

This results in a package validation error that "the error output has properties that do not match the properties of its corresponding data source column" and a validation status of "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

If I right-click the connection source, select Show Advanced Editor, and take a look at the Column Mappings, I can see that [Column1] in the Available External Columns list has a different Length than the datatype that was generated in the GetDropAndCreateDdl. I can delete and re-create the metadata mappings, but that is not a viable solution since there are many dataflow tasks.

How do I get GetDropAndCreateDdl to create the correct datatypes with correct lengths?

I am using ImportDB to get the list of tables, metadata, etc.

**Environment.biml**

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OdbcConnection Name="OdbcSrc_DV" ConnectionString="Dsn=Source-32bit-test;" />
        <OleDbConnection Name="OleDbDst_Staging" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=SQL-DEV;Initial Catalog=Source_Staging;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    </Connections>
    <Databases>
        <Database Name="Source" ConnectionName="OdbcSrc_DV" />
        <Database Name="Source_Staging" ConnectionName="OleDbDst_Staging" />
    </Databases>
    <Schemas>
        <Schema Name="dbo" DatabaseName="Source" />
        <Schema Name="dbo" DatabaseName="Source_Staging" />
    </Schemas>
</Biml>
```

**CreateTableMetadata.biml**

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.SchemaManagement"  #>
<#
var sourceConnection = RootNode.DbConnections["OdbcSrc_DV"];
var importResult = sourceConnection.ImportDB("", "", ImportOptions.ExcludeForeignKey | ImportOptions.ExcludeColumnDefault | ImportOptions.ExcludeViews);

var tableNamesToImport = new List<string>() { "Test_Table" };
#>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Tables>

    <# foreach (var table in importResult.TableNodes.Where(item => tableNamesToImport.Contains(item.Name)).OrderBy(item => item.Name)) { #>

    <Table Name="<#=table.Name#>" SchemaName="Source.dbo">
      <Columns>
            <#=table.Columns.GetBiml()#>
      </Columns>
      <Annotations>
        <Annotation AnnotationType="Tag" Tag="SourceSchemaQualifiedName"><#=table.SchemaQualifiedName#></Annotation>
      </Annotations>
    </Table>
    <# } #>
  </Tables>
</Biml>
```

**DeployTargetTables.biml**

```
<#@ template tier="2" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="MasterTableDeploy" ConstraintMode="Parallel">
      <Tasks>
        <# foreach (var table in RootNode.Tables) { #>

        <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL CREATE <#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="OleDbDst_Staging">
          <DirectInput><#=table.GetDropAndCreateDdl()#></DirectInput>
        </ExecuteSQL>
        <# } #>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

**CreateLoadPackages.biml**

```
<#@ template tier="2" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="Copy Data" ConstraintMode="Parallel">

      <Tasks>
        <# foreach (var table in RootNode.Tables) { #>
        <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL TRUNCATE <#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="OleDbDst_Staging">
          <DirectInput>TRUNCATE TABLE <#=table.Name#></DirectInput>
        </ExecuteSQL>
        <Dataflow Name="DFT LOAD <#=table.Schema.Name#>_<#=table.Name#>">
            <PrecedenceConstraints>
                <Inputs>
                    <Input OutputPathName="SQL TRUNCATE <#=table.Name#>.Output" />
                </Inputs>
            </PrecedenceConstraints>
          <Transformations>

              <OdbcSource Name="ODBC_SRC <#=table.Name#>" Connection="OdbcSrc_DV">
              <DirectInput>SELECT <#=table.GetColumnList()#> FROM <#=table.GetTag("SourceSchemaQualifiedName")#></DirectInput>
              </OdbcSource>

            <OleDbDestination Name="ODBC_DST <#=table.Name#>" ConnectionName="OleDbDst_Staging">
              <TableOutput TableName="<#=table.ScopedName#>" />
            </OleDbDestination>
          </Transformations>
        </Dataflow>
          <# } #>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Here is the script that gets created from the ODBC source -

[image]

And here are the results from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for the same table -

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed any particular data types that result in incorrect types and length in the biml? Got a minimal reproduction for us? What version of SQL Server (I assume) are you connecting to?

Comment: I have only noticed that nvarchar types are being changed. In the example above, I am expecting [Column 1] to be a nvarchar(30), but using GetDropAndCreateDdl, it's coming over as a nvarchar(45). Updated my question to include the BIML scripts.

Comment: I'm [not seeing it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3BqjN.png) with my [elementary version of the script](https://gist.github.com/billinkc/7b42479ba9669e944fb194e2285dcae8). I need to run but I'll try and take a look at what you're specifically doing later on

Comment: Look at the SQL Script in the previous comment's link. There are two queries: one uses information_schema and the other uses the sys views. Do you get consistent metadata between those two queries. You're using ODBC connection, are you certain that you're accessing a SQL Server on the backend? `SELECT @@VERSION` would reveal that. And for what it's worth, I'm fairly certain I used that product for logging time - you have my condolences.

Comment: Thanks, luckily I am not an end-user :) I ran the script and both the .sql file and .getBiml file have identical incorrect outputs (i.e. nvarchar(45)). The version revealed it is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4416.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor). I'm going to keep plugging away and hopefully find something useful.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with the ODBC Driver I was using. There was a setting to "Enable WChar Support", which was checked by default. Once I unchecked it, the data type Lengths were corrected, but I am still getting Unicode characters by default.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the newer method: GetDatabaseSchema? I've found it to be much more reliable across different connection types.

http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/07/12/biml-extension-methods-getdatabaseschema/

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I am using an ODBC source, so I will have to modify that example and see if it works. She uses an OLEDB source.